# How to pass a value to async function in JS

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I am trying to understand how to fetch data from an external API using async / await. I'm trying to fetch data from the openFDA API. When the user type in a medication the API retrieve the data and display it to the webpage. The input value is not being passed to the async function.

I have looked at other tutorials but it confused me more.

```
//listens for the submit event and calls the getMeds function
const myForm = document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit',getMeds);
```

```
// get the input value from the user
function getMeds(e){
    const meds = document.querySelector('#searchbox').value;

    console.log(meds);

     e.preventDefault(); 

};
```

```
//get medication information from the OpenFDA API

const getMedicine = async (meds) => {

    const base = 'https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json';
    const query = `?search=openfda.brand_name:${meds}%limit=5`;

    const response = await fetch (base + query);
    const data = await response.json();

    return data

    };

     getMedicine()
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I expected the .json object to be displayed in the console. What it done so far is logging the input value to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass anything to the method:

```
getMedicine()
```

Notice the various ways you pass values to methods throughout your code:

- `querySelector('#form')`
- `addEventListener('submit',getMeds)`
- `querySelector('#searchbox')`
- `log(meds)`
- etc.

That's exactly how you pass a value to a method.  Including it directly or as a variable when calling the method.  Whatever value you want to pass to your method, pass it:

```
getMedicine(someValueHere)
```

For example, if you call it within your submit handler:

```
function getMeds(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const meds = document.querySelector('#searchbox').value;
    getMedicine(meds) // <--- pass the value to the function
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```